# Eclipse (mars?), is there a 'workspace' or 'project' management perspective that is sharable?

Tags: eclipse

So, I work in an environment where we have ~20 different workspaces (solution).

Each project has its own subversion source location.  However an Eclipse workspace may contain 1-5 projects for the 'solution', where an Eclipse workspace = solution (a DTO project, commons project, database project, UI project combine to single solution for example).

I know some people work with one workspace with all projects (so up to 100 projects in one workspace), and that is not desired for when bringing in someone new.

Desire: Is there a plugin or perspective that can pull from a centralized location to setup these defined workspaces (solutions), including setting perspectives with subversion configurations for the 1-5 projects for that workspace (solution)?

Intent is to configure/setup one a 'portfolio of solutions' or other term of all the workspaces each configured with subversion repos already setup, and share it with other team members.

Slightly similar findings:

- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/workspace-preferences-transferrer
- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/workspace-mechanic
- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/yatta-launcher-eclipse

Comment: Eclipse can only deal with one workspace at a time.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to the '5 last workspaces you used', but larger scale.

Comment: Shareable is the reason you use Git or Subversion to keep source code.

Answer (score 0):

Each Eclipse workspace is, by design, independent of any others. The UI that shows the last recently used workspaces is just a (rudinemtary) convenience; there is not really any management of workspaces per se.
Having said that, the [Oomph project](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph) provides, among other things, a preferences recorder. You can read all about it [here](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/november/article2.php), but the gist is:

**An Eclipse installation with Oomph installed can record all preferences changes that the user makes, and then automatically apply them to any other workspaces that are created or opened with that installation.**

It's not clear if the recorded preferences can be easily shared with other users; for that answer I'd suggest engaging the Oomph team on the [dedicated forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/287/).

Oomph is included in at least some of the Mars downloadable packages, so you likely already have it. If not, it's easy to install.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Eclipse Profiles](http://profiles.yatta.de) ->  https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/yatta-launcher-eclipse

With Eclipse Profiles there is a Launcher which allows you to manage (start, share and install) all your Eclipse and Workspace combinations.
You can also share the plugins, Workspace and preferences with yourself or your teammates.

Because the sharing of preferences is in a beta status right now you have to enable the Preference recorder for the Workspace first.

Comment: I did look at this, but it appeared that the only storage was the centralized/public Yatta rather than a local profiles server. Also didn't appear to share, for example, the subversion configurations for each project.